# ASP.NET Session and Page Life Cycle

Tags: asp.net, session, lifecycle, pageload, page-lifecycle

Let's say that in an ASP.NET `.aspx` page I have the `Page Load` method and another method for a button click event.

In the `Page Load` method I'm checking if the user is logged in by checking the Session. Whether he is or not, I'm storing the result in a Global Variable.

```
Boolean isGuest = false;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        if(Session["id"]==null)
              isGuest = true;
        else
              isGuest = false;
}
```

Let's say 20 minutes have passed, and I don't know if the Session has terminated or not, and then I click a Button, the event goes like this:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if(isGuest==false)
                 //do something
            else
                 // do another thing
}
```

My Question is : When I'm clicking the button, does ASP.NET go through the `Page_Load` method again (check `isGuest` again) or it simply executes what's inside the `Button_Click` method, means, it uses a `Boolean isGuest` that could be `false`, but in reality the session is terminated, means it should be `true`.

Comment: Why no simply test it?

Comment: @RononDex It is tested and working but I just wanna make sure that nothing goes wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Page_Load` is triggered **always before** the control events.

Have a look: [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Side-note: If you want to do things only on the first load and not on every postback you have to check the `IsPostBack` property.

Answer (score -3):

You can:

1. Define your own class with the `UserID`, and other profile properties;
2. Add that class to session in the global.asax session started event `Session["NameReferingToYourClass"] = new YourClass();`
3. Set a member variable to your session object early in the page life cycle `mYourClass = Session["NameReferingToYourClass"]` casted if you need to;
4. Then you can make any changes to your class anywhere in the code your member variable is available;
5. Save back your class with all the changes into session on the `Page.Unload(..){ Session["NameReferingToYourClass"] = mYourClass`.

This way you are using your class properties in your code, including `UserId`, pretty much like a windows application, there will be no mentioning of session anywhere else in your code.

Comment: This seems completely unrelated to what the question is asking.